# What is the practice for scheduling multiple inter-dependent SQL Server Agent jobs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, scheduled-tasks

The way my team currently schedules jobs is through the SQL Server Job Agent. Many of these jobs have dependencies on other internal servers which in turn have their own SQL Server Jobs that need to be run to keep their data up to date.

This has created dependencies in the start time and length of each of our SQL Server Jobs. Job A might depend on Job B finishing, so we schedule Job B a certain estimated time in advance to Job A. All of this process is ***very subjective*** and not scalable, as we add more jobs and servers which create more dependencies.

I would love to get out of the business of subjectively scheduling these jobs and hoping that the dominos fall in the right order. I am wondering what the accepted practices for scheduling SQL Server jobs are. Do people use SSIS to chain jobs together? Is there tooling already built into the SQL Server Job Agent to handle this?

What is the accepted way to handle the scheduling of multiple SQL Server jobs with dependencies on each other?

Comment: Do you use any third party job scheduling tool such as Control M?

Comment: @Rajiv Not at the moment, feel free to leave an answer on how Control M could make scheduling our jobs more manageable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used Control-M before to schedule multiple inter-dependent jobs in different environment. Control-M generally works by using batch files (from what I remember) to execute SSIS packages.

We had a complicated environment hosting 2 data warehouses side by side (1 International and 1 US Local).  There were jobs that were dependent on other jobs and those jobs on others and so on, but by using Control-M we could easily decide on the dependency (It has a really nice and intuitive GUI). Other tool that comes to my mind is Tidal Scheduler.

There is no set standard for job scheduling, but I think its safe to say that job schedules depend entirely on what an organization needs. For example Finance jobs might be dependent on Sales and Sales on Inventory and so on. But the point is, if you need to have job inter dependency, using a third party software such as Control-M is a safe bet. It can control jobs on different environments and give you real sense of the company wide job control.

Answer (score 2):

We too had the requirement to manage dependencies between multiple agent jobs - after looking at various 3rd party tools and discounting them for various reasons (mainly down to the internal constraints relating to the use of 3rd party software) we decided to create our own solution.

The solution centres around a configuration database that holds details about processes (jobs) that need to run and how they are grouped (batches), along with the dependencies between processes.

Summary of configuration tables used:

Batch - highlevel definition of a group of related processes, includes metadata such as max concurrent processes, and current batch instance etc.
Process - meta data relating to a process (job) such as name, max wait time, earliest run time, status (enabled / disabled), batch (what batch the process belongs to), process job name etc.
Batch Instance - the active instance of a given batch
Process Instance - active instances of processes for a given batch
Process Dependency - dependency matrix
Batch Instance Status - lookup for batch instance status
Process Instance Status  - loolup for process instance status

Each batch has 2 control jobs - START BATCH and UPDATE BATCH. The 1st deals with starting all processes that belong to it and the 2nd is the last to run in any given batch and deals with updating the outcome statuses.

Each process has an agent job associated with it that gets executed by the START BATCH job - processes have a capped concurrency (defined in the batch configuration) so processes are started up to a max of x at a time and then START BATCH waits until a free slot becomes available before starting the next process.

The process agent job steps call a templated SSIS package that deals with the actual ETL work and with the decision making around whether the process needs to run and has to wait for dependencies etc.

We are currently looking to move to a Service Broker solution for greater flexibility and control.

Anyway, probably too much detail and not enough example here so VS2010 project available on request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much this will help, but we ended up creating an email solution for scheduling.

We built an email reader that accesses an exchange mailbox.  As jobs finish, they send an email to the mail reader to start another job.  The other nice part, is that most applications have email notifications built in, so there really isn't much in the way of custom programming.

We really only built it in the first place to handle data files coming in from lots of other partners.  It was much easier to give them an email address rather than setting them up with an ftp site, etc.

The mail reader app now has grown to include basic filtering, time of day scheduling, use of semaphores to prevent concurrent jobs, etc.  It really works great.